# How to get the all UILocalNotification fired userinfo?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iOS alarm app using local notifications. I am getting 3 notifications. When I click on a notification, I can get the data from that notification. How can I get the data from all 3 notifications just by selecting one of them. Below is my code-

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
     UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

        NSLog(@"DEMO");
        NSDictionary *dict = [localNotif userInfo];
        //        id obj = [dict objectForKey:@"TESTKEY"];
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification1234 %@",dict);

        if (localNotif)
        {
            // code here.
            NSLog(@"DEMODATA");
            NSDictionary *dict = [localNotif userInfo];
    //        id obj = [dict objectForKey:@"TESTKEY"];
            NSLog(@"Recieved Notification1234 %@",dict);
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           ^{
                               NSLog(@"DEMODATAlanunching");
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber -= 1;
                               UIAlertView *alet=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"app not56 running" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                               [alet show];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifMainController" object:localNotif.alertTitle];
                           });
        }
      }



      - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
    {
     NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
      dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                       ^{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifMainController" object:notification.alertTitle];
                       });
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain a bit what do you want to do?

Comment: i fired local notification next next interval ,i got all notification on notification center but if i can get one notification information,i cannot get reming notification information inside the app

Comment: `UILocalNotification` and `NSNotificationCenter` are two different things and I hope you already know that. Are you trying to send the information contained in the `userInfo` dictionary of a local notification via notification center to one of your view controller classes?

Comment: Yes,i am sending notification userInfo my view controller.

Comment: If you want to access all the notifications that are scheduled to be fired in the future then you can access those notifications from your application's shared instance like this `NSArray<UILocalNotification*> *allNotifications = [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications;`
each member of this array will be a `UILocalNotification` instance. You can iterate through this array to get the `userInfo` of each notification. Is that what you want?

Comment: It is working fine but  it is not coming  today notification details.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your question. For the clarity I just want to tell you that this array contains only those notifications that have not been fired yet. To access the details of a notifications that have been fired, you can access the details of a single notification using this function `UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];`.
If there's something else that you want to know please feel free to ask.

Comment: i got your points.i created notification today and tomorrow.Today alarm fired i got the information following code
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
The following code is showed only tomorrow details not showing on today
NSArray<UILocalNotification*> *allNotifications = [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications;

Comment: So is it working now? Should I post it as an answer?